# Expanding region/selection for javascript

Tags: filetype-javascript, selection

is there a way to configure https://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region (or any other plugin) to work with `js`,`jsx`,`ts`,`tsx` files?

I'm new to vim, I'm not sure what to do.

---

- The mentioned plugin is not active since 2013.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I believe you just want to use `expand_region#custom_text_objects` with keys suitable for those filetypes. Can you try that and [edit] to clarify the specific issues you are having? As it stands, your question is a little broad/lacking detail

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but I have no clue what is the proper configuration for JS/TS (or where to find it). From your comment, I assume that my question is ambiguous. Sorry for that.

Comment: Ambiguous only because I’m not sure (a) what’s not working and (b) what your goals are! Again, feel free to [edit] to clarify!